# Why isn't data being pulled from database when I load the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have a button that's supposed to run a function when loaded.

```
return (
      <>
        <LikeButtonStyle onLoad={getUserData} onClick={addInfo}>
          <Image width="10px" height="auto" src="/like-svgrepo-com.svg"></Image>
          <> {likeCount} </>
        </LikeButtonStyle>
      </>
    );
```

the function it's supposed to run is

```
async function getUserData() {
    const docSnap = await getDoc(userCollectionRef);
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      setUser(docSnap.data().username);
      setUserLikes(docSnap.data().likePost);
      if (userLikes == 'no') {
        setLikeCount('0');
      } else {
        setLikeCount('1');
      }
    }
  }
```

So the idea is that when the page loads, it grabs the user data which is made up of two fields **username** and **likePost**. Once it grabs that data it's supposed to set that data in state.

It uses this data to count a 0 or 1 depending if the user has liked it or not.

Comment: Please share your `LinkButtonStyle` component.

Comment: LinkButtonStyle is just a .styled.ts file containing all the CSS styling.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

If you're not attributting the `onLoad` property to a valid HTML tag somewhere inside your `<LikeButtonStyle />` component, it's not loading because `onLoad` only works in some tags, below is the list, according to w3s [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp):

```html
<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script> and <style>
```

I'd suggest you use `useEffect` to execute code you need to execute when the component renders

Comment: That's not true. `LikeButtonStyle` is a React component that can have an `onLoad` prop.

Comment: @kaveh the onLoad property is from HTML, nothing to do with React, if you pass `onLoad` to the component, it will do nothing, because you're very likely not doing anything with it on the component end. But if you are, the property will only work as intended if addded to one of the supported tags

Comment: If it is beign added on a supported tag, then my answer is wrong, but the question lacks the information to tell whether the `onLoad` prop is beign used somewhere in the button component

Comment: You're confusing different concepts here. You can create a React component that has a prop called `onLoad`. The question lacks details for sure, but you cannot assume that within this context the button cannot have `onLoad`.

Comment: I might have misinterpreted, but it feels like OP is trying to trigger `onLoad` directly from the component, as if it was a `<img>` or any of the supported tags. If that's the case, it is not going to work

Comment: No confusion at all, just assumed he was trying to use `onLoad` directly on the component without attributing it somewhere inside the component. If he is doing something with it, I hope op edits the question so we can help accordingly

Comment: editted the answer for clarification